# undefined reference to functions that have implementation

Tags: c++

I'm using a class of threads with a header and cpp file.
When I put both of them and empty test file it writes:

```
g++ -g -pedantic -ansi -Wall -Werror -std=c++03 -I../include  -c -o test.o test.cpp
g++ -g  test.o thread.o   -o test
thread.o: In function `Thread::~Thread()':
/home/tomer/work/mt/hash2/cpp/thread.cpp:15: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
thread.o: In function `Thread::start()':
/home/tomer/work/mt/hash2/cpp/thread.cpp:40: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
thread.o: In function `Thread::join()':
/home/tomer/work/mt/hash2/cpp/thread.cpp:49: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
thread.o: In function `Thread::cancel()':
/home/tomer/work/mt/hash2/cpp/thread.cpp:58: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
thread.o: In function `Thread::detach()':
/home/tomer/work/mt/hash2/cpp/thread.cpp:66: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I just tried to comppile Thread.h and Thread.cpp

```
//Thread.h looks like this:
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>

class Thread
{
public:
    Thread(size_t a_userID = 0);
    virtual ~Thread();

    bool start();
    void join();
    void cancel();
    void detach();


private:
    static void* threadMainFunction(void *);
    virtual void run() = 0;
    bool isAlive(std::string a_msg);

private:
    bool m_joinable;

protected:
    pthread_t m_threadID;
    size_t m_userID;
};

#endif

//Thread.cpp looks like this:
#include <exception>
#include "Thread.h"
#include <iostream>
Thread::Thread(size_t a_userID)
: m_joinable(true)
, m_threadID(0)
, m_userID(a_userID)
{
}

Thread::~Thread()
{
    if(m_joinable)
    {
        pthread_detach(m_threadID);
    }
}

void* Thread::threadMainFunction(void *a_thread)
{
    Thread* thread = reinterpret_cast<Thread*>(a_thread);
    try
    {
        thread->run();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<<"what exepction\n";
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool Thread::start()
{
    int r = pthread_create(&m_threadID, 0, threadMainFunction, this);
    return r == 0;
}

void Thread::join()
{
    if(isAlive("Thread::join on thread not started"))
    {
        void *status;
        pthread_join(m_threadID, &status);
        m_joinable = false;
    }
}

void Thread::cancel()
{
    if(isAlive("Thread::cancel on thread not started"))
    {
        pthread_cancel(m_threadID);
    }
}

void Thread::detach()
{
    if(isAlive("Thread::detach on thread not started"))
    {
        pthread_detach(m_threadID);
    }
}

bool Thread::isAlive(std::string a_msg)
{
    if(m_threadID == 0)
    {
        throw(std::runtime_error(a_msg));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Appears you did not supply the pthread library to `g++`.

Comment: `-lpthread` or `-pthread` should do.

Comment: BTW. why not use `std::thread`?

Comment: Why `-std=c++03`? Go for `-std=c++11` at least. You'll then have `std::thread` available as @Yksisarvinen suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing here is not a build issue, but a **link** issue. When building `thread.o`, the compiler knows `pthread_create` exists and is defined somewhere because declared in the `pthread.h` header.

If you used `nm` to look at the symbols used in `thread.o`, you would see something similar to this:

```
U _pthread_create
U _pthread_detach
...
```

This tells you that `thread.o` references multiple **U**ndefined symbols including `pthread_create`. In other words, the machine code for `pthread_create` is unknown at this point. This is perfectly fine until you need to **link** your object files into an executable file, which is the role of the linker.

At this stage, you must tell the linker where to find these undefined symbols, perhaps from another object file or a static/shared library. For `pthread`, the symbols are defined in `libpthread`, which you can likely find in a system directory as `libpthread.a`. You can tell `g++` to link this library by adding `-lpthread` (note that `lib` from `libpthread` is omitted when using `-l`):

```
g++ -g test.o thread.o -o test -lpthread
```

In general, if you use symbols referenced in a static library `lib${LIBNAME}.a` available in `${LIBDIR}` directory, you can tell the linker to use it with:

```
g++ -g *.o -L$LIBDIR -l${LIBNAME}
```